# Can 802.11 a/b/g/n adapter sniff a b g n traffic simultaneously in monitor mode?

Tags: wireless-networking, monitoring, 802.11n, 802.11

I have wifi adapter based on rt5572 which supports a/b/g/n. And let's say I have Mixed mode wifi network where there is AP and a, b, g, n wifi clients all in the same network.

The questions I have:

Question 1:
If I put my rt5572 wifi adapter into monitor mode and start sniffing 802.11 packets in the air, will I be able to see all management frames, control frames and data frames from a, b, g, n clients if my monitor mode adapter is in same channel as them?

Question 2:
If my wifi adapter in monitor mode can capture all a, b, g, n traffic in the same channel(including data traffic, not just management and control frames in legacy rate) from a, b, g, n wifi clients, how is this possible because a,g,n PHY layer technology is OFDM but 802.11b PHY layer technology is DSSS. Does my WiFi adapter detect modulation and decode a,b,g,n traffic accordingly even if 802.11b use different PHY modulation?

These are questions I have for long time since gotten into Kali and wifi sniffing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your sniffer WNIC in monitor mode will attempt to decode any and every packet transmitted on the channel, regardless of the frame type and regardless of which modulation scheme each transmission uses, as long as it's a modulation scheme that your WNIC knows how to decode.

Please note that A is only defined for the 5GHz band, and B/G is only defined for the 2.4GHz band, so you'll never have A clients on the same channel as B/G clients.

Supporting DSSS and OFDM at the same time is not hard, and is not specific to monitor mode. The very first G equipment in late 2002 had to do this to be backwards compatible with all the existing B (and 802.11-1997 DSSS) equipment that was already deployed. Every Wi-Fi card that supports the 2.4 GHz band (and G or later) does this all the time in normal operation.

Comment: Thanks and I'll adapt this as an answer. 
If you don't mind, I'd like to ask slightly different question as you seem very knowledgable about wifi. 
Now if I associate wifi a/b/g/n wifi adapter with AP and use it as normal STA, then how does it know there is 802.11b STA in the network and use DSSS modulation so that 11b client(and other g,n clients) knows I'm about to transmit traffic etc.

Comment: @greenfrogs In general, this site works best if you ask one question per Question post, and create additional Question posts if you have additional questions, rather than asking followup questions in the comments. And in this case, while the answer to your followup question is straightforward, it's a little too long to fit within the comment length limit. If I see you ask it as a separate Question post, I'll answer it there.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate.